# regex on a string to return text after last colon

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following regex:

```
:57[^:]?:*[^:]*
```

which i'm trying to create to return everything after the last colon:

***EDIT***
    :57A:/19000019

```
SOMEMORETEXT
:59:xxxxxxxx
```

it shouldn't return anything from the preceding tag, or previous tag, but I can only get it to return the following:

```
:57A:/19000019 SOMEMORETEXT
```

Which includes the :57A: - I do however require the forward slash, and another character after the final :

***EDIT***
Ok, so i'm moving forward. I now use this is c#:

```
var result = Regex.Match(message, String.Format(":{0}[^:]?:*[^:]*", tag ));
```

which now returns all the items i need, but all in one string, including the tag, which i don't need. How can i know take this string and create an array/list based on the \n?

Comment: What exactly is the expected result?

Comment: /19000019 SOMEMORETEXT  @kamilkp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try maybe lookbehind

```
(?<=\:\w{2,3}\:).*
```

Comment: Can you review the change above, I need to capture information over two or more lines

Comment: how do You provide the line for the regex evaluation? Is it line by line?

Comment: yes, it's a string, of a raw text file, which contains carriage return lines feeds.

Comment: sorry maybe I don't see exactly the problem, if You provide line by line then You can use the regex for each of particular Strings

Comment: No, it's one block of text, the :59: above is a subset. I don't want to loop through each line, as the file is very large, I want to single out specific tags, in this instance :59:

Answer (score 0):

`/^\(.*:\)*\(.*\)$/\2/` will do the trick.
You can test this with:

```
echo ':57A:/19000019 SOMEMORETEXT' | sed -e 's/^\(.*:\)*\(.*\)$/\2/'
```

If it is possible then I would recommend trying to 'split' the string on its delimiter instead though (using something other than a regex, such as a 'Split' like function) since this is probably more reliable and certainly more efficient.